# GitHub Actions dotnet nuget pack error : Description is required

Tags: .net, nuget, github-actions

I am trying to run a `dotnet pack` command in GitHub Actions workflow like so:

```yaml
- uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
  with:
    dotnet-version: '3.1.x'
- name: Publish the package to nuget.org
  shell: powershell
  run: |
    cd "Martin Nuget Work"
    dotnet pack template.csproj -p:NuspecFile=template.nuspec -p:PackageVersion=3.3.3 --output ./nupkg
    dir
  env:
    NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NUGET_API_KEY }}
```

Running the command:

```bash
dotnet pack template.csproj -p:NuspecFile=template.nuspec -p:PackageVersion=3.3.3 --output ./nupkg
```

locally works fine.

I have the description field set in both my `csproj` and `nuspec` files. But when the GitHub Actions workflow runs, it fails with this error:

```
    cd "Martin Nuget Work"
    dotnet pack template.csproj -p:NuspecFile=template.nuspec -p:Description="myDesc" -p:PackageVersion=0.0.0 --output ./nupkg
    dir
  shell: C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR: C:/temp/action_runner_dotnet
    NEW_VERSION: 0.0.0
    DOTNET_ROOT: C:\temp\action_runner_dotnet
    NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ***
MSBuild version 17.7.4+3ebbd7c49 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\actions-runner\_work\STPtest\STPtest\Martin Nuget Work\template.csproj (in 84 ms).
  template -> C:\actions-runner\_work\STPtest\STPtest\Martin Nuget Work\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\template.dll
C:\temp\action_runner_dotnet\sdk\7.0.405\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(221,5): error : Description is required. [C:\actions-runner\_work\STPtest\STPtest\Martin Nuget Work\template.csproj]
```

Giving me the error:

> error : Description is required

Am I not setting the description correctly?

Here is my `template.csproj`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
     <metadata minClientVersion="3.3.0">
        <!-- Required elements-->
        <id>PrTemp.FPRemove</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <authors>Automated System Test</authors>
         <description>Cool Description</description>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <repository type="git" url="https://github.com/repo" branch="(branch)" commit="(commit)" />
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="P\s\**" target="" />
        <file src="R\s\**" target="" />
    </files>
</package>
```

and my `template.nuspec`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <!-- NuGet Package Info -->
    <PackageId>prt.fpga</PackageId>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Description>Hard Coded Desc</Description>
    <Authors>Your Name</Authors>
    <Company>Your Company</Company>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Both have descriptions.

Comment: Do you have a description in your .nuspec file?

Comment: Updated my post, I have description set in both files, and the command works when running locally, but on the same machine, the github actions script fails saying no description

Comment: @POVR2: The logs show that the command includes `-p:Description="myDesc"` also but the command in your workflow and the one you run locally don't include this. You need to verify and fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to this kind of questions is challenging due to the multitude of potential factors contributing to the problem.

However the error is self explanatory: "it doesn't find the description xml node within your csproj file".

I can list some potential fixes / things you should check:

1. Make sure that both you local machine and the build server are using the same .NET Core SDK version.

   dotnet pack --version
2. The nuspec file is not required for sdk-style projects (like netstandard2.0). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format
   Make sure your csproj file is compliant to the sdk-style format and try to pack it without the nuspec file.
   Check this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format#check-the-project-format

In this case you would just need to run this command:

```
dotnet pack template.csproj -p:PackageVersion=3.3.3 --output ./nupkg
```

3. Make sure your github action is checking out the latest version of your code and it has a clean working folder before starting.